# Ask Core Data to grab data if it exist on another table. Objective C

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Currently I'm trying to Query using Core data the following.

[image]

**I want to Query:**

*All the Rooms that exist on Room_messages.*

Currently I've the following code.

```
// Initialize Fetch Request
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Rooms"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"room_messages.@count > 0"];
    // also tried room_messages.@count != 0 but the same thing no results
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"last_seen_date" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                        managedObjectContext:[[coreDataHelpers sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    BOOL success = [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    if (!success) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"FetchedResultsController failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
```

This is a Chat room conversation List. I need to show the user only the Rooms that contains messages. The ones that don't have messages on Room_messages don't need them.. until They have messages on my Query Results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter for those rooms that have a message count of zero. Assuming the to-many relationship to "Message" is called `messages`:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"messages.@count > 0"];
```

Comment: I updated my Question description and added images can you please review it.. based on the NSPredicate you did. thanks

Comment: Updated my answer and still does not work.. any ideas based on the images @mundi

Comment: I should work. You probably did not assign the messages to the room.

Comment: I did @mundi but it isnt showing any results I get 0 rows.

Comment: This is strange. If the predicate is not correct, it normally throws an error. Try with `= 0` and see if you get *all* the records that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I've found to my issue that provided the result I wanted, even though I don't know if its the best one. Is that I had to add this line of code before I'd save the new incomming message.

```
[messageObject addRoomsObject:roomObject];
```

RoomObject its simply the key value for that specific message's room so lets say I insert a new message. this message belongs to a specific room. and this room value is the one that I get in result of that key. so my final code is.

```
// Create a new managed object
    Message *messageObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Message"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:[[coreDataHelpers sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];

    messageObject.message  = payload[@"message"];
    messageObject.date = [NSDate date];
    messageObject.type_message = payload[@"type_message"];
    messageObject.room_key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", payload[@"room"]];
    messageObject.user_id = payload[@"user_sender"];
    messageObject.read = @YES;
    // Make relation between both Entitites
    [messageObject addRoomsObject:roomObject];

    NSError *error;
    BOOL saved = [[[coreDataHelpers sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] save:&error];

    if (!saved) {
        if (error) {

            [self makeAlert:@"Error"
                   subTitle:error.localizedDescription
                   buttonOk:@"Ok"];

        }
    }
    else {
        [SimpleAudioPlayer playFile:@"message_sent.aiff"];

        [[coreDataHelpers sharedInstance] lastSeenRoom:payload[@"room"] lastMessage:payload[@"message"]];
        [[coreDataHelpers sharedInstance] updateLastSeenDateUser:payload[@"user_sender"]];

    }
```